# Excel - Comparing specific date and times

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to create a tracker that contains a column to check if we've met SLA.

```
Column A - Date Received
Column B - Time Received
Column C - Date and Time Combined (A2+B2)
Column D - Date Resolved
Column E - Time Resolved
Column F - Date and Time Resolved (D2+E2)
```

Essentially, what I need to check is:

If the date received (Column A) and time received (Column B) was after 12 PM, the date resolved (Column D) should be the next business day by 12 PM (Column E).

Ex: Received request at 2pm on Monday July 31st, resolved Tuesday August 1st at 11 AM -> SLA Met

Ex: Received request at 2pm on Monday July 31st, resolved Tuesday August 1st at 3 PM -> SLA Not Met

I can't figure out how to combine the date and time data to plug into my formula. I've tried combining the date and time as you can see above:

```
=IF(AND(O2="Team Inbox", C2 >= TIME(12,0,0)), NETWORKDAYS(A2,E2,Holidays[2023Holidays])<=2, G2  <= TIME(12,0,0)), "Yes", "No")
```

`Column O = Specific Inbox`

`[2023Holidays] = Table of holidays for business`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Here's one: in the second AND condition you are comparing a date-time (column C) to a time. I believe as written this would always be true.

Comment: Note: Excel stores dates+Time as date count from `1899-12-30` (Enter a zero in a cell, format it as Date). In addition the time of day is included as the decimal part of that number. So typing in `1.5` in a non-date cell will show `1899-12-31 12:00:00` when the cell later is set to be Date+Time formatted. This fact may well make your calculations easier.

Comment: Thanks, any suggestions on how to change the formula so it works?

Answer (score 0):

The formula in the OP has mismatched brackets - the are 5 opening and 6 closing brackets. Given the structure of the formula it is reasonable to assume that there is a spurious closing bracket and that the `AND` function is intended to have four conditions:

- `O2="Team Inbox"`
- `B2>=TIME(12,0,0)` note `C2` (date+time) in OP corrected to `B2` (time) here
- `NETWORKDAYS(A2,E2,...)<=2`
- `G2<=TIME(12,0,0)`

All 4 conditions must be met for the formula to deliver "Yes", otherwise the result is "No".

This seems a bit curious. Particularly, the conditions on the Team Inbox and the time received.

In terms of performance measurement, it seems likely that there will be the following quantities of interest

- Total tickets received
- The subset of the total received through the Team Inbox of which
- The total resolved within the deadline
- The total not resolved within the deadline

Rather than a simple "Yes"/"No" result, it seems possible (likely?) that there is an additional outcome which applies to tickets not received through the Team Inbox (otherwise why is the Specific Inbox being recorded against each ticket and why does the OP make use of this data?).

In addition, the OP states the target is to resolve tickets(?) received after 12 noon by 12 noon the following working day. Unstated is the target for tickets received before 12 noon. It seems odd that the formula in the OP will deliver a "No" for such tickets and I suspect this is not what is intended.

There are two more likely possibilities for tickets received before 12 noon:

1. These tickets are classed alongside those not received through the Team Inbox (ie no requirement to state whether the target was met) or
2. The target is to resolve the ticket on the same working day it is received.

For case 1:

```
  =IF (
       OR  (
            O2<>"Team Inbox",
            B2<TIME(12,0,0)
           ),
       "-",
       IF  (
            AND (
                 E2<=TIME(12,0,0),
                 NETWORKDAYS(A2,D2)<=2
                ),
            "Yes",
            "No"
           )
      )
```

The outcomes are:

- `"-"` when either the `Specific Inbox` is not the `Team Inbox` OR the time received is before noon, otherwise it is
- `"Yes"` when the target of completion deadline of noon on the next working day is met and
- `"No"` when the target of completion deadline of noon on the next working day is not met

For case 2:

```
=IF (O2 <> "Team Inbox",
     "-",
     IF  (B2<TIME(12,0,0),
          IF  (NETWORKDAYS(A2,D2)<=1,
               "Yes",
               "No"
              ),
          IF  (
               AND (
                    E2<=TIME(12,0,0),
                    NETWORKDAYS(A2,D2)<=2
                   ),
               "Yes",
               "No"
              )
         )
    )
```

The outcomes in this case are:

- `"-"` when the `Specific Inbox` is not the `Team Inbox`, otherwise it is
- `"Yes"` when the ticket is received before 12 noon and the target of completion on the same working day is met
- `"Yes"` when the ticket is received after 12 noon and the target of completion on the next working day is met
- `"No"` when the target completion is not met.

The two cases above may well not properly represent what the OP intends. However, they should underline the importance of analysing a situation and identifying all the rules and cases as part of the solution process.